# Action Script problems with adobe Flash builder

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I have been given a repository full of Mxml and .AS files. The task is to edit a wack a mole game.

I have loaded the repository into the flash builder by using new -> Flex Project then i set the project location to the root repository.

It has now been loaded into flash builder but when i click run maingame on the maingame file, it doesn't run, i get an error message saying

```
File not found: file:/C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/DubitPlatform-Co/bin-debug/MainGameView.html
```

any ideas where i am going wrong?

Thanks

here is the code for the maingameview.mxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<views:MainGameViewBase xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         xmlns:views="uk.co.dubit.whackamole.views.*"
         xmlns:components="uk.co.dubit.whackamole.views.components.*"
         styleName="stretchToContainer">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Sequence id="startAnimation" effectEnd="startAnimationEnd()">
            <s:Sequence id="readyAnimation" target="{readyLabel}" >
                <s:Parallel duration="400">
                    <s:Fade alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" />
                    <s:Scale scaleXFrom="0" scaleYFrom="0" scaleXTo="1" scaleYTo="1" />
                </s:Parallel>
                <s:Pause duration="1000" />
                <s:Fade alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="100" />
            </s:Sequence>
            <s:Sequence id="goAnimation" target="{goLabel}" >
                <s:Parallel duration="400">
                    <s:Fade alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" />
                    <s:Scale scaleXFrom="0" scaleYFrom="0" scaleXTo="1" scaleYTo="1" />
                </s:Parallel>
                <s:Pause duration="1000" />
                <s:Fade alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="100" />
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Sequence>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" gap="10">

        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="10">

            <s:BorderContainer styleName="roundedBorder" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" width="66%" height="100%" >

                <s:Label id="readyLabel" text="Ready?" fontSize="72" color="0xffffff" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" alpha="0">
                    <s:filters>
                        <s:GlowFilter color="0x000000" strength="10" />
                    </s:filters>        
                </s:Label>

                <s:Label id="goLabel" text="Go!" fontSize="72" color="0xffffff" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" alpha="0">
                    <s:filters>
                        <s:GlowFilter color="0x000000" strength="10" />
                    </s:filters>        
                </s:Label>

                <s:DataGroup
                    id="moleHolesDataGroup"
                    dataProvider="{ moleHoles }"
                    itemRenderer="uk.co.dubit.whackamole.views.MoleHoleItemRenderer"
                    verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:TileLayout requestedRowCount="3" requestedColumnCount="3" horizontalGap="10" verticalGap="10" />
                    </s:layout>             
                </s:DataGroup>
            </s:BorderContainer>

            <s:VGroup width="33%" height="100%" gap="10">

                <s:BorderContainer styleName="roundedBorder" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" width="100%" height="30" >
                    <s:Label text="Achievements" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" />
                </s:BorderContainer>

                <s:BorderContainer styleName="roundedBorder" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" width="100%" height="100%" >

                </s:BorderContainer>    

            </s:VGroup>

        </s:HGroup>


        <s:BorderContainer styleName="roundedBorder" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" width="100%" height="30" bottom="10" >
            <s:Label text="Score: { mainGame.score }" left="10" verticalCenter="0"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>

    </s:VGroup>

</views:MainGameViewBase>
```

Im not 100% sure that this is the file that i should run to be able to play the game. Which would the file be that makes the game executable?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not getting generated. Following are some try which i can say...

```
Does your bin-debug has MainGameView.html
```

1. Can you post down your MainGameView.mxml file, there should be some error which is not generating your html output.
2. Delete the contents of maingame.mxml file and just include the Application tag alone, see whether you are able to generate MainGameView.html in bin-debug

Comment: @Tom: Whats is your main file where this View is getting called... i mean some where in your project should be Application Tag